# Expected value of a random variable whose PMF contains negative value in its image

Tags: probability, expected-value

The definition of Expected Value in the **first course in probability by Sheldon Rosss** is defined as

$$E[X] = \sum_{x:p(x)\gt0} xp(x)$$

where the negative outputs of PMF is ignored in calculating the expectaion.

I saw the following in a different book where they are considering the negative value while calculation expectation.

```
If P(W=−3)=0.2, and P(W=−11)=0.7, andP(W=31)=0.1.
Then E(W)=(−3)(0.2)+(−11)(0.7)+(31)(0.1)=−0.6−7.7+3.1=−5.2.
In this case, the expected value of W is negative.
```

Is my interpretation of the formula incorrect ?

Comment: The values taken by $X$ can be negative but not the pmf $P[X=x]$; pmf is a probability.

Comment: Thanks. $X$ is a random variable which is a function, So isn't saying "Output of a random variable can be negative" is correct, rather than "The values taken by $X$"  or is this the convention widely used.

Comment: Both mean the same thing.